# Warning:no previous prototype for function 'delay' in KEIL

Tags: c, stm32, keil

I am getting the warning "no previous prototype for function 'delay'" on the following code.

```
void delay()
{
    for (int i=0;i<100000;i++);
}
    
int main()
{
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN;
    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER5_0;
    
    while(1)
    {
        GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS_5;
        delay();
        GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR_5;
        delay();
    }
}
```

Comment: just declare `delay` to be `static`...

Comment: It has to be void delay(void) ....

Comment: @Peter it is not the solution and static does not have any influence here

Comment: BTW this code will not blink the LED. One of the assignments has to be `GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR_5 + 16;`

Answer (score 2):

Functions have global scope by default, here the compiler is warning you that there is a function defined as global without a previous prototype, that is, it is visible or callable from another translation unit (poluting name spaces).

Simply declare the function as static (only for internal use in this file):

```
static void delay(void) { ... }
```

Also prefer `void delay(void)` (function without arguments) than `void delay()`(function with undefined number of arguments)